# How does App Engine handle authorization between services?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have Google Cloud App Engine application, which consists of two services: 1) Default, the backend service, written in Flask on Standard Environment and 2) Frontend, a Node JS Website, on Flexible Environment. The backend service has its ingress settings set to "Internal traffic only", as I only want it accessible by the frontend service.

I am trying to make API calls from the frontend to the backend with a basic fetch:

`fetch('https://my-url.com/api/hello-world', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }).then(response => { return response.text(); })`

This returns 403 not authorized error.
However, if I log onto the frontend instance via SSH, open up a Python shell and do
`print(requests.get("https://my-url.com/api/hello-world").text)`
it works.

I don't understand what's happening here. Why does access work in one case, but not the other if it's the same machine? What do I have to change in the frontend code for the request to be successfull?

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake. Think about from where your request is sent?

It's not from the App Engine service, it's from your browser. The App Engine service serve the statics JS file, but then run OUTSIDE AppENgine, on the client side, on the browser.

What do you have to change?

Set the backend service to external.

---

And even if your traffic would be sent from your front end service, think about the backend: it accepts only internal traffic. i.e. only the traffic coming from the VPC of the current project (or from the VPC SC).

That means, you should create a serverless VPC connector to route all the traffic from App Engine frontend to the VPC of your project to be authenticated and accepted as "internal" traffic on the internal only App Engine backend service.